# How can I display the value of a field in WordPress?PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/index.php/products_categoryproducts_cate/coffe/)

I installed the plugin Types and tried this code to display the value field in a div.

```
<div class="selectat">
<div>
<?php $variable = do_shortcode("[types field='descriere' ]");?>
<?php echo $variable;?>

</div>
</div>
```

My field is called descriere..I put a picture to see more clearly.

[image]

Unfortunately this blank although I do not see anything on the site and basically my div is empty ..

[image]

It is wrong the way I wrote the code?
I must call another function?

You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use any shortcode you could use

```
<div class="selectat">

    <div>
        <?php $variable = the_field( 'descriere' );
        <?php echo $variable;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if you want to echo the code straight away you can just use get_field('')  which echos the value straight to the page.

```
<div class="selectat">

    <div>
         <?php $variable = get_field( 'descriere' );
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/dgsite81/public_html/bagel/bagel/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/archive.php on line 23

Comment: are you using custom fields pro?

Comment: Tell me what custom field plugin your using and I should be able to answer I think the syntax is slightly different?